# How to solve repetitive ORA-2391 error in DBeaver 4.3.3.1

Tags: oracle, session, dbeaver

I can't seem to find the way to avoid ORA-2391 "exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit" when working with DBeaver 4.3.3.1. Everytime my session goes idle and I need to recconect I'm getting this error. I'm not sure if this is a DBeaver issue or I am missing something in my Oracle connection configuration.

I already talked with DBA and he showed me that whenever I connect to my database DBeaver creates two sessions (two rows in table v$session) and when he tries to kill them, they hang out for a while.

I am sure I don't have any other session opened with another tool.

My goal is to keep working with DBeaver since this tool has some amazing features, but without having to bother my DBA everytime I can't connect due to simultaneous sessions.

If there could be any way to stop DBeaver from creating more than one session for just one connection, I will appreciate any help.

PS:(I hope I'm clear with my question, English is not my native language)

Comment: Can you provide an example of code? If it is not related to coding/programming, maybe you have to post this in a different channel than stackoverflow.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer you are right, haven't realised maybe this question doesn't belong here, I'm moving it to DBA SE.